# JavaScript Initialize Function

Tags: javascript, function, declaration

I've recently been following some coding tutorials and I've gotten decent in my general JS knowledge (still have a ton to learn of course). On just about every tutorial I follow.. The code contains this or something like it.

```
    initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.store = new MemoryStore(function() {
        self.renderHomeView();
    });
```

Specifically

```
    initialize: function() {
        // code in here
    }
```

I honestly just don't know what this is. Sure, I can finish following a tutorial just fine.. However, I want to understand what it is that I'm coding. Not just copy what someone else has written.

I've tried to use google to find out more about this, but I honestly don't have any clue what search terms to use.

Is this a way to declare a function?
As in:

```
functionName: function(){
    // code here
}

// vs

function functionName(){
    // code here
}
```

What am I missing? Could someone send me a link to a resource for this?

```
            Thanks, Jay
```

Comment: It's part of an object literal.

Comment: for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
functionName: function() {
    // some code
}
```

This is declaring an object property called functionName with a value that's an anonymous (unnamed) function. This would only occur within curly braces defining an object literal. It's different from the following, which declares a named function in the current scope, but isn't a property of any object:

```
function functionName() {
    // some code
}
```

You can learn more about object literals here: [MDN Grammar Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)